# Unable to iterate over an array passed through data, but when I make a variable of the exact same array then it works

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is the array that's passed through to my ajax call:

`data.comments`

```
[['rwerw', '215', '/news/215/'], ['wrwerwer', '215', '/news/215/'], ['Woinfoqf', '215', '/news/215/'], ['Good', '215', '/news/215/'], ["He's good", '215', '/news/215/']]
```

If I do:

```
data.comments.forEach(function(a, index) {
          console.log('new', a);
        });
```

the `forEach()` does not work and I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.comments.forEach is not a function
  at Object.success (base.js:180)
  at i (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2)
  at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2)
  at z (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4)
  at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4)
```

But if I make a variable of the exact same array, then it works:

```
    var arr = [['rwerw', '215', '/news/215/'], ['wrwerwer', '215', '/news/215/'], ['Woinfoqf', '215', '/news/215/'], ['Good', '215', '/news/215/'], ["He's good", '215', '/news/215/']];

    arr.forEach(function(a, index) {
      console.log('new', a);
    });
```

console.log:

```
new ["rwerw", "215", "/news/215/"]
new ["wrwerwer", "215", "/news/215/"]
new ["Woinfoqf", "215", "/news/215/"]
new ["Good", "215", "/news/215/"]
new ["He's good", "215", "/news/215/"]
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Edit: ajax call:

```
$('#user_comments').on('click', function () {
    var user = $(this).data('user');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/profile_comments/',
        data: {
            user: user
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.comments);

            var arr = [['rwerw', '215', '/news/215/'], ['wrwerwer', '215', '/news/215/'], ['Woinfoqf', '215', '/news/215/'], ['Good', '215', '/news/215/'], ["He's good", '215', '/news/215/']];

            arr.forEach(function(a, index) {
              console.log('new', a);
            });

        }
    })


});
```

Comment: the first A in AJAX stands for Asynchronous - without seeing the code, I'm guessing you are accessing the results before the Asynchronous function gets them

Comment: Have a look at: [`promise.prototype.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

Comment: I `console.log(data.comments)` and it logs the same array so I'm definitely getting data

Comment: please show the AJAX call, and how you are trying to access the data - I'm almost 100% sure it's the Asynchronous nature of AJAX that is tripping you up ... the console is useful for debugging, but it can lie if you don't know how to use it correctly

Comment: @JaromandaX: I'm assuming that using ajax he might benefit from the use of a promise, rather than trying to use the data immediately. Although I may be misunderstanding? Admittedly, though, since jQuery is being used it's probably easier to use the jQuery methods. And yes, I forgot that the success function isn't a method of the prototype - I removed that part. >.<

Comment: jquery does have "promises" (broken in parts) - my comment was because you originally had just promise.prototype.then (that should be Promise.prototype.then anyway) - besides, I don't think using Promises (es6 or jQuery) is going to help the OP understand Asynchronous code

Comment: It's just a regular ajax call, the `forEach` is in the `success` function. I've added it in my edit.

Comment: hmmm. so assuming you meant `data.comments.forEach` where you just posted `arr.forEach` - the only issue is ... is `data.comments` an ARRAY? what does `console.log(Array.isArray(data.comments))` give you?

Comment: Yes it is an array because I `console.log(data.comments)` and it is the same array.

Comment: so, it's not a JSON string - it's a javascript Array - so my suggestion logs **true** not **false**

Comment: Wow I just tried that and it's saying false (`arr` variable says true). That's weird any idea why this is happening?

Comment: did you try $.each(data.comments, function(index,value){ console.log...})

Comment: Yeah same error. Managed to solve it by using `makeArray()` on `data.comments`

Answer (score -1):

`data.comments` is passed through as a string not an Array.

```
console.log(Array.isArray(data.comments)); // false
var data = $.makeArray(data.comments); 
console.log(Array.isArray(data)); // true
```